# When running this code, why does the loop not wait for my response?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite

```
import random

def rock_paper_scissors(choice):
    computer_choice = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
    while True:
        if choice == computer_choice:
            print("Tie! Play again.")
            choice
        elif choice.lower() == 'quit':
            break

        elif choice.lower() == 'rock' and computer_choice.lower() == 'paper':
            print("TRY AGAIN!", computer_choice.lower(), "beats", choice.lower())
            choice
        elif choice.lower() == 'rock' and computer_choice.lower() == 'scissors':
            print("YOU WON!", choice.lower(), "beats", computer_choice.lower())
            choice
        elif choice.lower() == 'paper' and computer_choice.lower() == 'scissors':
            print("TRY AGAIN!", computer_choice.lower(), "beats", choice.lower())
            choice
        elif choice.lower() == 'paper' and computer_choice.lower() == 'rock':
            print("YOU WON!",  choice.lower(), "beats", computer_choice.lower())
            choice
        elif choice.lower() == 'scissors' and computer_choice.lower() == "rock":
            print("TRY AGAIN!", computer_choice.lower(), "beats", choice.lower())
            choice
        elif choice.lower() == 'scissors' and computer_choice.lower() == "paper":
            print("YOU WON!", choice.lower(), 'beats', computer_choice.lower())
            choice
        else:
            print("Sorry, invalid.")
            choice

print(rock_paper_scissors(input("Rock paper or scissors (enter 'q' to quit): ")))
```

When this code is run,  whatever is in the print in the elif is repeated over and over and over again in the run box. I don't know if I should fix the while statement or add additional code in the elif statements. The input works fine, but I don't know what to add to the while loop. (I am a beginner Python programmer)

Comment: `while True:` will by definition repeat over and over and over again unless you have some way to break out of the loop. I think you just want to delete the `while` statement.

Comment: You have to request user input instead of putting `choice` statement (which has no effect). HINT: You can request user input only one time after all `if`s check

Comment: @dcg why did you write it in comment? It's exactly the answer... Even stackoverflow discorages to give an answer in comment ans use it only for addition info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input statement is not in the scope of the while loop, so it is only called once.

Once in the while loop, there is nothing changing the choice variable and hence the same print statement get triggered over and over.

Moving the input statement into the while loop along with the the computer choice initialisation (so the computer can choose a new option each go) solves your problem.

```
import random
def rock_paper_scissors():  
    while True:
        computer_choice = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
        choice = input("Rock paper or scissors (enter 'q' to quit): ")
        if choice == computer_choice:
            print("Tie! Play again.")
        elif choice.lower() == 'quit':
            break
        elif choice.lower() == 'rock' and computer_choice.lower() == 'paper':
            print("TRY AGAIN!", computer_choice.lower(), "beats", choice.lower())
        elif choice.lower() == 'rock' and computer_choice.lower() == 'scissors':
            print("YOU WON!", choice.lower(), "beats", computer_choice.lower())
        elif choice.lower() == 'paper' and computer_choice.lower() == 'scissors':
            print("TRY AGAIN!", computer_choice.lower(), "beats", choice.lower())
        elif choice.lower() == 'paper' and computer_choice.lower() == 'rock':
            print("YOU WON!",  choice.lower(), "beats", computer_choice.lower())
        elif choice.lower() == 'scissors' and computer_choice.lower() == "rock":
            print("TRY AGAIN!", computer_choice.lower(), "beats", choice.lower())
        elif choice.lower() == 'scissors' and computer_choice.lower() == "paper":
            print("YOU WON!", choice.lower(), 'beats', computer_choice.lower())
        else:
            print("Sorry, invalid.")
rock_paper_scissors()
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd share an alternative way of writing this that may be of help to a beginner.  The goals are:

1. To reduce repetition, so you only have one `print("You Lose")` rather than three.
2. To separate the winning logic into a separate function, which makes it easier to test the logic part and allows code reuse.

```
import random

def did_player_win(computer, player):
    # Returns None for a tie, True for a win, False for a lose

    if computer == player:
        return None

    if computer == 'paper':
        return False if player == 'rock' else True

    if computer == 'scissors':
        return False if player == 'paper' else True

    if computer == 'rock':
        return False if player == 'scissors' else True


def play():
    while True:
        player = input("Rock, paper or scissors (enter 'q' to quit): ")
        player = player.lower()
        if player not in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']:
            break

        computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])

        player_won = did_player_win(computer, player)
        if player_won is True:
            print("YOU WON! {0} beats {1}".format(player, computer))    
        elif player_won is False:
            print("TRY AGAIN! {0} beats {1}".format(computer, player))
        else:
            print("Tie!  Both chose {0}".format(player))

play()
```